# Method 'Count' of object 'HPageBreaks' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with MS Excel VBA on HPageBreaks.
The Sheets("Temp").HPagesBreaks.Count works fine when I run the code line by line in testing. But when I tried to run the full code, my Excel gets frozen and an error message pops up when I tried to close Excel.

There was a similar question a couple years back, by suggesting activate Sheets("Temp") before count method. 
I've tried Sheets("Temp").Activate before HPageBreaks.Count, but it doesn't work in my scenario.

Here's part of my code, and the error message.
I want to resize all shapes in the sheet, until they are all fit into one page.
Print Settings are pre-set.
Does anyone know what caused it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSP6m.jpg)

```
Do Until ((xWMax > 600 And xWMax <= 680) Or xH > 600) And Sheets("Temp").HPageBreaks.Count = 0
If Sheets("Temp").HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then
    ....
End If
```

Loop

Comment: Is there more than one worksheet open? Try  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Hpagebreaks.count

Comment: Hi Harassed Dad, no there's only one workbook opened. I've tried using "ThisWorkbook.", but same error comes up.

Answer (score 0):

The question is now resolved by activate other sheet and re-active sheets("Temp") before every HPageBreaks.Count will make the error gone.
Application.ScreenUpdate must be set to False